# Is there any API to query the status of a Peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I mean how know if the peer online or not, how many transactions/sec, for monitoring purpose?

I've tried searching the Node SDK design spec and no lucky.

Answer (score 0):

try the [blockchain explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer)
It's proposal and documents are [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z8uR_w9E9XITEe88PzkLjzH9t5bPivUhQO8OiEP7s_U/edit). It works for fabric v-0.6 (I used it in my project last year), but it seems not support fabric v1.0 at this moment.